# React Router Dynamic Routing causes an issue with fetch REST api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch

For a route that has a dynamic path, there is an issue when I make a rest api call in my component.

My render function contains:

```
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={home}></Route>
    <Route path="page1" component={page1}></Route>
    <Route path="page2/:id" component={page2}/>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

When on

`https://localhost:3000/page1`

I can make a fetch call such as

```
// Example.url = "/example"
fetch((Example.url), {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    "Accept": 'application/json',
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem('token')
  }
}).then((response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then((responseData) => {
  this.setState({
   ...
  })
});
```

This call makes a request to https://localhost:3000/example

However, I jump to page 2 from page 1 using

```
browserHistory.push('/page2/' + uuid)
```

Now when on

```
https://localhost:3000/page2/someuuid1234
```

I make a fetch call but my the call is made to

```
https://localhost:3000/page2/myendpoint
```

Why is page2 being appended to all my rest calls? This is causing a 404 request.

I'm assuming react router intercepts these calls and is listening to update the route. I would like to make a request to https://localhost:3000/myendpoint and receive a normal response.

Comment: why not use an absolute url for `fetch` instead of a relative one?

Comment: as @azium mentioned above. I don't understand the reason why you can't have absolute path for your rest API calls. Keeping them separate will always benefit you, since if tomorrow you decide to move your API host to another location, you would requires just a change in your base URL.

Comment: I'm using a relative path so it's flexible to my local and application environment. If I used an absolute URL then wouldn't the code only work to a specific database server? I want the code to look at the environment no matter which server it's running on.

Comment: @azium Oh I see what you and sumit are talking about. You mean in my browserHistory call to use /page2.. yes that worked for me.